# Can I write a code in groovy in wait for page load?

Tags: katalon-studio, winium

I'm using Winium automation tool for desktop apps that is integrated with Katalon Studio but I'm using static wait time, like Thread.sleep().

Sometimes page load is taking more than the time what I'm putting there.

So is there any way to use groovy code that will wait until the application loads successfully?

Comment: show your code how you loading page...

Comment: Are you testing a desktop app or a web app?

Comment: I'm testing desktop app

Answer (score 0):

In two ways, we can solve this issue

one increase the wait for page load option in Katalon

```
WebUI.waitForPageLoad(10, FailureHandling.STOP_ON_FAILURE);
```

Else use the custom fluent wait

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
.withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
.pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("object details")));
```